# How to make this code thread safe with openMP?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, openmp, pragma

The schematic code shown below works fine if I remove the  `#pragma omp parallel for`, but with this in place the code compiles but then upon executing the binary I get errors like `*** glibc detected *** ./testBin: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0c43d8d8 ***` and `core dumped`. I'm guessing that the reason is that multiple threads try to write to the variables `omega, ell, ....` or `lineVec`. How do I fix this? Is there a way to tell it the variables are shared? or is there just generally another way to do this loop in parallel. I am completely new to `openmp, this is the first time I have used it.

```
#include <omp.h>


int main( int argc , char **argv )
{ 
 vector <vector<string>> fileVec;
 //some code that reads in a CSV file lines into elements of fileVec

//variables constituting a line:
//my_float has been typedef to be a high precision class in real code
my_float omega;
my_float ell;

my_float init1Real;
my_float init1Imag;
my_float dinit1Real;
my_float dinit1Imag;

my_float init2Real;
my_float init2Imag;
my_float dinit2Real;
my_float dinit2Imag;

#pragma omp parallel for private(lineVec,fileVec,ell,omega,init1Real,init1Imag,dinit1Real,dinit1Imag,init2Real,init2Imag,dinit2Real,dinit2Imag)
 for (size_t i=0; i< fileVec.size(); i++) 
    { 

        lineVec=fileVec[i];


         ell=lineVec[0];
         omega=lineVec[1];

         init1Real=lineVec[2];
         init1Imag=lineVec[3];
         dinit1Real=lineVec[4];
         dinit1Imag=lineVec[5];
         init2Real=lineVec[6];
         init2Imag=lineVec[7];
         dinit2Real=lineVec[8];
         dinit2Imag=lineVec[9];


        // cout<<"OUTPUT ell=" << ell<< " omega=" << omega <<" init1Real="<<init1Real<<endl;

         //do some other calc involving these variables

    }     
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading from a shared `fileVec` *is* thread-safe. Only the variables of type `my_float` should be made `private` or even better - declared inside the loop:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<vector<string>> fileVec;

    //some code that reads in a CSV file lines into elements of fileVec

    #pragma omp parallel for private(lineVec)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fileVec.size(); i++)
    {
        lineVec = fileVec[i];

        //my_float has been typedef to be a high precision class in real code

        my_float ell = lineVec[0];
        my_float omega = lineVec[1];

        my_float init1Real = lineVec[2];
        my_float init1Imag = lineVec[3];
        my_float dinit1Real = lineVec[4];
        my_float dinit1Imag = lineVec[5];
        my_float init2Real = lineVec[6];
        my_float init2Imag = lineVec[7];
        my_float dinit2Real = lineVec[8];
        my_float dinit2Imag = lineVec[9];

        cout << "OUTPUT ell=" << ell << " omega=" << omega
             << " init1Real=" << init1Real << endl;

        //do some other calc involving these variables
    }
}
```

I don't see any races here unless `my_float` is not thread-safe or there is something else hidden in the `//do some other calc involving these variables`.

Note that with recent OpenMP versions you can even use iterators to walk the vector, since it provides a random access iterator:

```
typedef vector<vector<string>>::const_iterator iterType;

#pragma omp parallel for private(lineVec)
for (iterType it = lineVec.begin(); it != lineVec.end(); it++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: OK, that seems to work (except the strange `cout` behaviour of course). Is it really better to declare `ell,omega,..` etc inside the loop rather than make them private? either way seems to work in terms of no core dumps, but just wondering which is most efficient.

Comment: as for the `//do some other calc involving these variables`. One thing I do after the calculation for each `omega, ell` is write the results out to a file; the file is different for each loop (each `omega,ell` so this shouldn't cause any problems, right?

Comment: Variables declared inside a parallel region are automatically `private`. Also since parallel regions are usually extracted into separate functions, these variables won't take stack space in the parent function. And also in C++ and C99 it is a good programming practice to only declare variables in the scope where they are being used.

Comment: Writing to a separate file in each iteration should not be a problem. By the way, if you do not use `lineVec` outside of the loop, you can declare it inside and have the `privte(lineVec)` clause removed.

Comment: thanks, all seems to be working well now. Is it necessary for me to do things like set the number of cores etc or will this be taken care of automatically to use the max? anything else I need to do to improve execution speed? thanks again.

Comment: Bind the threads to the CPU cores. This will increase the performance slightly. But then again, you are writing files from inside the parallel region. IO is bandwidth limited - it doesn't usually go faster with many threads, although 2 threads might get better combined bandwidth than one.

Answer (score 1):

the way you wrote it, openmp will create some threads and divide the total number of iterations of the for loop between every threads. By doing so it will try to perform parallel reads on the vector shared by the different threads. You can change the data sharing attributes, (see [the OpenMP Wiki about data sharing attribute clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Data_sharing_attribute_clauses), and in this [microsoft doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3dabskb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you have a good example how to do it. For an example, to declare lineVec and fileVec as "private" use:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(lineVec, fileVec)
```

Moreover, cout is not thread safe and calls to cout from the multiple threads also need to be serialized.

Comment: thanks, but even doing `#pragma omp parallel for private(lineVec,fileVec,ell,omega,init1Real,init1Imag,dinit1Real,dinit1Imag,init2Real,init2Imag,dinit2Real,dinit2Imag)` and removing the `cout` hasn't stopped the `segmentation fault (core dumped)` errors at runtime. I should mention that `fileVec` is very large (it is the whole CSV file read in) so if this `private` makes lots of copies of it, maybe running out of memory could be an issue. I changed the code in the OP to what I have with your modifications.

Comment: Looking at the wiki article would I not want `fileVec` to be `firstprivate` to it gets initialized to its original value that I have set  by reading in the CSV higher up in the code? and only `omega, ell, init1Real...` that I set during the `for` to be `private`?

Comment: the size of `fileVec` is 67881, so not a multiple of 10. But the size of each of `fileVec` 's elements that set `lineVec` is always 10. In the real code I have an `if (lineVec.size() == 10)` wrapped around where I set `omega,ell,...` etc in the `for` loop.

Comment: The note about reading from a shared vector not being thread-safe is pure nonsense, unless the vector is being modified by some of the threads (which is clearly not the case here).